# Instantiating a value in or out of an always block

Tags: verilog

I have written a piece of code that will return a quotient and a reminder, based on numbers that i provide and some other data that i used to shift the numbers in place.
The problem I have now is that i cannot keep a good track of my quotient if I test more values one after another.
I need a way to initialize my **cat** register, so that I no longer get residual values from previous computations.

Here is the code I was talking about:

```
module divide(
  input      [7:0] a, b,
  input      [3:0] counter, msb,
  output reg [7:0] q,
  output reg [7:0] r
);
always @(*) begin
  for(i = 0; i < counter + 1  ; i = i+1) begin
    sum = s_a + s_b;     //previously calculated values
      if(sum[8-msb] == 1) begin
        assign s_a       = s_a; 
        assign s_b       = s_b >>> 1;
        cat[counter - i] = 1'b0;                
      end
      else begin
        assign s_a       = sum;
        assign s_b       = s_b >>> 1;
        cat[counter - i] = 1'b1;
      end
      assign r = s_a;
      assign q = cat;
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Note: I have declared all the registers that are in this code, but for some purpose I cannot declare them here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not use `assign` inside `always` or `initial` blocks.

The assignments to cat are combinatorial therefore it is not a flip-flop, ie has no reset. The fact that it is a `reg` type has nothing to do with the hardware but a simulator optimisation.

I would have written it as (no functional alterations made):

```
module divide#(
  parameter DATA_W = 8
)(
  input      [7:0] a, b,
  input      [3:0] counter, msb,
  output reg [7:0] q,
  output reg [7:0] r
);
//Definitions
reg [DATA_W-1:0] sum;
reg [DATA_W-1:0] s_a;
reg [DATA_W-1:0] s_b;
integer i;

always @* begin
  for(i = 0; i < (counter + 1); i = i+1) begin
    sum = s_a + s_b;     //previously calculated values
      if(sum[8-msb] == 1'b1) begin
       s_a              = s_a; 
       s_b              = s_b >>> 1;
       cat[counter - i] = 1'b0;                
      end
      else begin
        s_a              = sum;
        s_b              = s_b >>> 1;
        cat[counter - i] = 1'b1;
      end
      r = s_a;
      q = cat;
    end
  end
endmodule
```

You have the following line:

```
sum = s_a + s_b;     //previously calculated values
```

You have not included any flip-flops here, unless you have implied latches which are really to be avoided, there is no memory or state involved. i.e. there are no previously calculated values.

Instead of a combinatorial block you likely want to add a flip-flop and take multiple clock cycles to calculate the result.

instead of an `always @*` try:

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
     s_a <= 'b0; //Reset Value
  end
  else begin 
    s_a <= next value; //Normal logic
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I managed to get my `cat` register to re-initialize, just by adding `cat = 0` before my algorithm. It works this way.

Comment: @Bodizzy If you intend to synthesise this design I think you will run into problems, because of your for loop you are implying a dynamic amount of hardware. In your next iteration of the design I would recommend using a state machine to perform the variable loop and do 1 step per clock cycle. This would take counter clock cycles.

Comment: Technically you can use assign inside a prodecural block, but it's not really standard practice: http://verilog.renerta.com/source/vrg00037.htm